# Error message: Invalid form input message error issue

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have a Strapi backend and a React frontend. My Strapi backend has the following json fields for a Dogs collection type:

```
id, 
Breed,  
Name,       
image,
```

When creating new Dog objects in my frontend, I run into one of the input fields generating the following error:

> statusCode: 400, error: "Bad Request", message: "Invalid 'data' field.
> 'data' should be a valid JSON."

This only happens on the input field that takes in the Breed, the input field for Name and the file upload works if the Breed input field does not exist.

This is my code for the file Create.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default () => {
  const [Breed, setBreed] = useState('')
  const [Name, setName] = useState('')

  const [file, setFile] = useState(null)

  console.log('file', file)

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('data', JSON.stringify({ Breed }))
    formData.append('data', JSON.stringify({ Name }))

    formData.append('files.image', file)

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/dogs', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    })
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log('data', data)
  }

  return (
    <div className='Create'>
      <h2>Create</h2>
      <form action='' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='Breed'
          value={Breed}
          onChange={(event) => setBreed(event.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='Name'
          value={Name}
          onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <input
          type='file'
          placeholder='Add a image'
          onChange={(event) => setFile(event.target.files[0])}
        />
        <br />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

What am I missing in my code?

Comment: Try to send Breed  object without Name as form data, like this formData.append('data', JSON.stringify({ Breed })) and see if it works. My guess is it will work, since I don't see any issue with Bred input field.

Comment: It seems that only one input field works at a time. When I remove the Name field, then the Breed field works, if I remove the Breed field then the Name field works, but not both.

Comment: As @Matiarx mentions, I guess that the multiple JSON.stringify is the culprit, but I need to use formData.

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with your Bred field. When you are sending formData it will be send like this for example:  data : {"Bred":"test"} data : {"Name" : "test"} since formData will send it as multipart/form-data content type. The question is how do you handle this on server side?

Comment: The database does receive the newly created object, as long as I submit one JSON.stringify input, so the problem is in my code using JSON.stringify multiple times .
The file upload does not need JSON.stringify so that passes through also.

Answer (score 0):

Your `formData` will be send like this for example:  `data` : `{"Bred":"test"}` `data : {"Name" : "test"}` since `content-type` for `formData` is always `multipart/form-data` . The question is how do you handle this on server side? My guess is that you are picking up just one value for data, and therefore you are getting `error 400` since second value is not read properly. As far as I can see there are two ways to resolve this:

1. Add `JSON` data with different keys, for example like this :

   `formData.append('breedtest', JSON.stringify({ Breed }))`

   `formData.append('nametest', JSON.stringify({ Name }))`

and send it like this :

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/dogs', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    })
```

Than it will be easier to you to handle it on server side.

**OR**

2. Create JSON object from formData like this :

   `formData.append("Breed",  Breed );`
   `formData.append("Name",  Name );`

`const json = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData));`

and send `json` object as body of your request.

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/dogs', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: json,
    })
```

Comment: I tried it out, but I am getting back a empty object.
Can we set up a online code example with Code Sandbox?
My url for this project is https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-curie-p3ixk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you post your server side code? We can't use this sandbox since I don't have server running on localhost:1335 amd I won't be able to post data and get back response

Comment: Send data like this : formData.append('breed', JSON.stringify({ Breed }))
    formData.append('name', JSON.stringify({ Name }))
    formData.append('files.image', file) and then set body: formData as you were doing earlier, Or like this:
    formData.append('Breed', Breed)
    formData.append('Name', Name)
const json = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData)) ie just send this json variable in body, like this body:json do not send it like you are sending it in sandbox

Comment: I tried out both variants, the first creates a object with no data, the second generates: "statusCode: 400, error: "Bad Request", message: "When using multipart/form-data you need to provide your data in a JSON 'data' field.""
Can you update my sandbox or fork it and make your version or maybe we could screen share and I can show you my screen?
My server side code is generated by my strapi backend.